# how to reduce Build Context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile in which a 7GB SQL Server database bak file is being copied from the host.This increases the build context. If bak file is ignored in .dockeringore, COPY fails, as expected. How do I handle this without increasing the build context?

My Folder structure is

```
C:\proj
    artifacts (contains sql bak file)
    docker (contains dockerfile)
    scripts (contains powershell script for restoring db)
```

```
PS C:\proj> docker image build -t testdb:v14 -f .\docker\wcp_db.dockerfile .
```

Here, the build context includes the bak file and image size increases.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.196GB
```

If I add .gitignore to skip artifacts folder or skip bak file, build context gets reduced.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.26kB
```

However, `COPY` fails as expected since `.gitignore` ignores the folder/file from context.

```
Step 5/6 : COPY ./artifacts/testDB.bak .
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder101517566\artifacts\testDB.bak: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I believe, we cannot copy a file which is outside the build context.

My dockerfile is below:

```
#escape = `
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express:latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA="Y" `
    sa_password="someSApwd012#"

WORKDIR C:\workspace

COPY ./scripts/DeployDatabase.ps1 .

COPY ./artifacts/testDB.bak .

CMD powershell ./DeployDatabase.ps1 -sa_password $env:sa_password -dbName 'testDB' -serverName ".\sqlexpress" -sourceBackupFolder "C:\workspace" -Verbose
```

How to handle this situation, where I can still copy the bak file, and keeping build context at a minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually filtering of the build context is done using .Dockerignore file. If the bak is required for the image it has to be present in buildcontext AFAIK.

One way to overcome it is to provide some way of downloading the bak file in runtime. In this case you'll have to modify the CMD to run some script that first downloads the file and then runs the DB deployment script.

In this case, the image will be small, the build will be faster. However it's not really about docker ecosystem but more about how would you like to run the deployment process, if the absence of the backup image is acceptable in your case